# Use LINQ with GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, gridview, checkbox

I am new to web dev and using controls so please forgive me.

I have a GridView with check boxes in it (please see markup below)

When a user goes through and checks any boxes and hits my submit button
I want to run LINQ query to get all the rows with the checkbox1.checked = True

Something like:

```
Dim sList = (From row in Gridview1
             Where row.Cells("IsStarFleet") = True
             row.Cells("ID)).ToList
```

Markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="516px" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IsStarFleet">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack ="False" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Where do you want to use this query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `FindControl` for controls in a `TemplateField` and `Cells(index)` for `BoundFields`:

```
Dim checkedIDs = From row In GridView1.Rows.Cast(Of GridViewRow)()
                 Where DirectCast(row.FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox).Checked
                 Select row.Cells(0).Text
Dim checkedIdList = checkedIDs.ToList()
```

Comment: I tried this and althought the code seems to execute fine, it never gets any of the rows where I have checked anything.

Comment: @ChinaSyndrome: Maybe you are databinding your `gridView` also on postbacks. You should do that `If Not Page.IsPostBack Then grid.DataSource=... grid.DataBind() End If`.